# Grails REST controller responds with incorrect content type

Tags: rest, grails

I'm trying to write a Grails REST controller that should always respond with JSON. The controller is shown below:

```
class TimelineController {

    static allowedMethods = [index: "GET"]
    static responseFormats = ['json']

    TimelineService timelineService

    def index(TimeLineCommand command) {
        List<TimelineItem> timeline = timelineService.currentUserTimeline(command)
        respond timeline
    }
}
```

I'm using the `respond` method which is part of Grails' REST support, so content negotiation is used to figure out what type of response to render. In this particular case I would expect JSON to be chosen because the controller specifies

```
    static responseFormats = ['json']
```

Furthermore I've written (and registered with Spring) the following renderer to customise the format of the JSON that is returned for the `List<TimelineItem>`

```
class TimelineRenderer implements ContainerRenderer<List, TimelineItem> {

    @Override
    Class<List> getTargetType() {
        List
    }

    @Override
    Class<TimelineItem> getComponentType() {
        TimelineItem
    }

    @Override
    void render(List timeline, RenderContext context) {

        context.contentType = MimeType.JSON.name
        def builder = new JsonBuilder()

        builder.call(
            [items: timeline.collect { TimelineItem timelineItem ->

                def domainInstance = timelineItem.item

                return [
                        date: timelineItem.date,
                        type: domainInstance.class.simpleName,
                        item: [
                                id   : domainInstance.id,
                                value: domainInstance.toString()
                        ]
                ]
            }]
        )

        builder.writeTo(context.writer)
    }

    @Override
    MimeType[] getMimeTypes() {
        [MimeType.JSON] as MimeType[]
    }
}
```

I've written some functional tests, and can see that although my renderer is invoked, the resolved content type is `text/html`, so the controller returns a 404 because it can't find a GSP with the expected name.

I strongly suspect the problem is related to the use of a custom renderer, because I have another almost identical controller which doesn't use a custom renderer and it resolves the content type correctly.

Comment: Is `Accept` header set to `application/json`?

Comment: @dmahapatro I don't want to use the `Accept` header for content resolution, I **always** want to return JSON. I thought that adding `static responseFormats = ['json']` to the controller should ensure this

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on why do you actually want to use `respond` at all? When you don't use different mime types, you could get rid of the `respond` method at all, and use `render myList as JSON` instead?

Comment: @MarioDavid because if`respond` is called, Grails will use my custom renderer to generate the JSON. If I use `myList as JSON` then the default renderer will be used.

Comment: Should create a JIRA issue. I am able to replicate this in 2.4.4 and 2.5.0. Still looking into it.

Comment: Why you can't use default converter to JSON and reimplement it for this class, it more easy and cleaner, I think.

Comment: @Koloritnij reimplement what exactly?

Comment: @Dónal you can configurate how domain will be convert to json by JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Class name), if it interested you, I can write a full answer

Comment: @Koloritnij I know, this is the workaround I've used, but what I want to know is why the code above doesn't work (I'm pretty sure it's a bug in Grails at this point)

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you have to create a blank (at least) `index.gsp` under

```
grails-app/views/timeline/
```

to make the renderer work. I am successfully getting back content type as `application/json`

This behavior baffles me a lot and I am still looking into it. This is worth a JIRA issue. If you need I can push my dummy app to github.

**UPDATE:**
Issue created in github (with links to sample app).
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/716

Comment: Yes, if you could push your dummy app to GitHub and/or raise a JIRA that would be very helpful. Having done some research myself, I'm beginning to suspect that it's not possible have a container renderer for a type, unless you also have an individual renderer for for that type. However, the docs don't mention this, and I don't see any logical reason why this should be the case, so I agree that it's worth a JIRA.

Comment: App is similar to what is being portrayed in the question. Here is the issue in github. https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/716

Comment: nice job on the JIRA issue and demo app, I've added a comment to the issue

Answer (score 0):

1. In Config.groovy, `grails.mime.types` needs to be specified.
   The details could be found out here: [Grails 2.3.11 Content Negotiation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.11/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation). At least you need to have the following in Config.groovy:

   ```
   grails.mime.types = [
       json: ['application/json', 'text/json']
   ]
   ```
2. If you want to respond with customized JSON, `render someMap as JSON` is recommended.
3. About your 404 problem, you need to do `response.setContentType('application/json')` in your controller action. Grails' default response format is html, so that it will look for the gsp file to render if the contentType is not specified.

Comment: 2. If I use `render someMap as JSON` then the default JSON rendering will be used, i.e. `TimelineRenderer` will not be invoked

Comment: 3. I shouldn't need to set the content type header, Grails' content resolution should choose JSON based on `static responseFormats = ['json']`

Comment: render([timeline: timeline ] as grails.converters.JSON) tried this ?

Comment: Grails controller has its own keyword "response". You could do 
`response.contentType = 'application/json'; `
`response.setContentLength(content.bytes.size()); `
`response.outputStream << content.bytes; `
Here content is a serialized String for the json.